# Python CSV Re indexation

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to re-order a column on my CSV File: the normal order is from line 2 to line 19 : from 2-10 is Male and 11-19 Female. (check picture "Data")

[image]

I want a script that re-order like this: make the first column of each gender the last one (check picture "Data Re indexation")

[image]

**This is the code i tried till now :**

```
import pandas

columns_labels = ['State', 'Capital', 'Population', 'Sports_Teams']
data = pandas.DataFrame({'State': ['Indiana', 'Massachusetts', 'Illinois', 'test'],
                                               'Capital': ['Indianapolis', 'Boston', 'Springfield', 'test'],
                                               'Population': [6_600_000, 6_800_000, 12_800_000, 0000],
                                               'Sports_Teams': ['Pacers', 'Celtics', 'Bulls', 'test']
                                               }, index=list('1234'))
print(type(data))
print(data)
data_reindex = data.reindex(index=list('2341'))
print(data_reindex)
```

1- It doesn't import data from CSV

2- It reindex the whole line, i want to re index only the first column (A)

Comment: Could you provide a code example of what you tried so far?

Comment: @NicolòGasparini Here, i added the code i tried

Comment: If you move values in column A around while keeping columns B, C, D etc. the same, wouldn't that result in garbled data? I mean, what are you trying to accomplish exactly?